# How do I avoid spurious merge conflicts when rebasing a branch onto rewritten history?

Tags: git

In my workplace, we use a rebase workflow. I recently helped three of my colleagues with the following problem, so I figured it was worth posting a Q&A to help more people and provide a reference to point my coworkers at.

Suppose I run the following series of commands to create a git repository and initialize it with some data and a single commit.

```
git init .
cat > MyFile.txt <<'EOF'
> Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3
> Line 4
> EOF
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

Then, I make a branch and add a commit to modify a particular line.

```
$ git checkout -b MyFeature
Switched to a new branch 'MyFeature'
$ ed MyFile.txt
28
2s/$/ This is the initial implementation of my glorious feature
Line 2 This is the initial implementation of my glorious feature
wq
86
git add -u
git commit -m 'WIP Add glorious feature'
```

After sending it off for review, I then work on a different feature that depends on this feature, and make a new commit.

```
git checkout -b MySecondFeature
cat >> ThisFileDependsOnMyFile.txt <<'EOF'
> This commit touches a completely different file.
> EOF
git add ThisFileDependsOnMyFile.txt
git commit -m 'Add Feature2'
```

Now my reviews for the first feature come back, so I make some changes to it and then merge it into master.

```
git checkout MyFeature
sed -i '2s/initial/final/' MyFile.txt
git add -u
git commit --amend -m 'Add glorious feature'
git checkout master
git merge MyFeature
```

Finally, I attempt to rebase MySecondFeature onto master. Unfortunately, it blows up, even though the new commit on MySecondFeature does not even touch the file that conflicts.

```
git checkout MySecondFeature
git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: WIP Add glorious feature
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       MyFile.txt
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging MyFile.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in MyFile.txt
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 WIP Add glorious feature
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

**How does one avoid these spurious merge conflicts when branching off a branch that subsequently has its history rewritten?** Note that we can always manually fix the conflict, but it's a pretty huge waste of time to keep doing this.

To make this easier to discuss, here are a couple of hashes:

```
git log MySecondFeature
hq6:GitPlay hqin$ git log
commit 061fc8448e93f0e31239b2f4806d5caac6bfe578 (HEAD -> MySecondFeature)
Author: ***
Date:   Sun Dec 15 15:36:21 2019 -0800

    Add Feature2

commit f878084412c04542e297cb5c52b0fb6f6a2b2870
Author: ***
Date:   Sun Dec 15 15:30:45 2019 -0800

    WIP Add glorious feature

commit fe88218ac2432e086a40f052bfa4e7c759f677b4
Author: ***
Date:   Sun Dec 15 15:26:18 2019 -0800

    Initial commit


git log master
commit 522cc625b709b37c4ccfd1878465f8da30f9e082 (master, MyFeature)
Author: ***
Date:   Sun Dec 15 15:30:45 2019 -0800

    Add glorious feature

commit fe88218ac2432e086a40f052bfa4e7c759f677b4
Author: ***
Date:   Sun Dec 15 15:26:18 2019 -0800

    Initial commit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to do this using an interactive rebase and dropping any commits that shouldn't be there:

```
git rebase -i master
```

Your git editor will open with a file that lets you reorder, edit, and delete commits. In this case we just want to delete the now non-existent MyFeature commit, which is done by putting "drop" before the commit hash:

```
drop f878084 WIP Add glorious feature
pick 061fc84 Add Feature2

# Rebase 522cc62..061fc84 onto 522cc62 (2 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

And now you can see that the rebase succeeded:

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/MySecondFeature.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to avoid manually resolving the spurious merge conflict.

#### Skip the conflicting commit

Since we don't actually care about f878084412c04542e297cb5c52b0fb6f6a2b2870, we can simply skip it during the rebase.

```
git rebase master
# Bunch of merge 
git rebase --skip
```

#### Tell rebase explicitly which part of the history to rebase

This is my favorite solution. One can run `git rebase` with `--onto` and pass the target branch followed by the parent of the oldest commit on MySecondFeature that we care about.

```
# Get out of the merge conflict situation
git rebase --abort

git rebase --onto master 061fc8448e93f0e31239b2f4806d5caac6bfe578~1
```

#### Cherry pick

We can create a temporary branch starting at the history we want and cherry-pick the commits from MySecondFeature that we want.

```
# Get out of the merge conflict situation
git rebase --abort

git checkout -b TempBranch master
# Note that if there are multiple commits we care about on MySecond Feature, these should be cherry-picked either individually or together in the right order.
git cherry-pick MySecondFeature
git checkout MySecondFeature

# Note that this command will blow away changes in your working directory.
git reset --hard TempBranch

# git branch -d TempBranch
```